# FlipView-Item swipe navigation for pages (c# & XAML)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

In my project I have several pages which navigate through with an Manipulation-Started, Delta events that checks if I am sliding far enough.
If that is the case I m using `this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(anotherPage);`, almost like FlipView sliding through items.

It kind of works, but if the page I am using this function in has an `ScrollViewer` in it which have other handlers in it, my function no longer works that well.

I am wondering if there is a solution to my problem?

Is it possible to have an FlipView and the items is loaded pages ?

EDIT*

```
private void grid_ManipulationStarted(object sender, ManipulationStartedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        initialPoint = e.Position;
    }

    private void grid_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Point currentPoint = e.Position;
        if (currentPoint.X - initialPoint.X >= 100)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(DIStatePage), ts);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
        else if (currentPoint.X - initialPoint.X <= -100)
        {
            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(PassagePage), ts);

            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

This is how my navigation function looks like..
and i would like it to be more like flipping inside a FlipView

And for the ScrollViewer problem i can set the ScrollViewer ManipulationMode="All", but of course the handlers withing the ScrollViewer stops working.
And it works the same way with other controls as well..

Comment: Paste some example code please. If you use ScrollViewer inside FlipView item it's doesn't work yes?

Comment: The thing is i don't use FlipView as it is now..
I just want to resemble the FlipView flip funktion from item to item.. But instread of items such as pictures.. i want to flip from one page to another.

Comment: And im using Manipulation functions to read the mouse/point movement as it is now but that is not the best solution i think.